# Black on white unfortunately turned into white on black

Tags: texstudio

Suddenly, my monitor started to show me compiled text which is white on black, instead of black on white.

The saved pdf-file remains black on white.

How may I revert the shown text to be black on white?

Comment: Which operating system, editor, viewer, TeX installation...? This question lacks *any* detail... (Cristal ball guess: some automatic dark mode kicking it?)

Comment: @Rmano I use Texstudio 4.3.1, and macOS Big Sur v. 11.7.1. The TeX installation is TeX-live.

Comment: If it’s only happening with TeXStudio check to see if you changed a Preference to Dark Mode. If it’s happening with all apps check to see if there is a change to Dark Mode in System Preferences. This has nothing to do with TeX as your pdf is fine.

Comment: @HerbSchulz It is only happening with TexStudio, and I do not see that I changed a preference to Dark Mode. I shall need to ask my technician for help.

Comment: Right click in the pdf and check if you have "invert colours" checked https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHiqB.png

Comment: If you have a problem with a specific editor, don't you think it would make sense to actually mention the name of the program in your question?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 

"Right click in the pdf and check if you have "invert colours" checked .."

Thanks, that resolved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texstudio has an option to invert the colours of the pdf viewer. To undo this, right click in the pdf and uncheck "Invert Colors":

[image]